# Vue: function not defined in create hook

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I can't call function in the create hook. I always get the error 'loadEmployees is not defined'. Why is this not working?

```
export default {
components: {
    AppointmentSlot
},
data: function() {
    return {
        employees: [],
        appointmentData : {
            date: Number,
            employee: String,
            slotSize: Number
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    onRequestSlots() {
        console.log(this.appointmentData.date);
    },
    loadEmployees: function() {
        console.log('loading...')
    }
},
created() {
    console.log('asd');
    loadEmployees();
}
}
```

When I call the function on a button click and not in `create`it works...

Im using Nuxt.js. Does this have to do with the error?

Comment: `this.loadEmployees()`

Answer (score 1):

`loadEmployees` should be called with `this`:

```
this.loadEmployees()
```

```js
new Vue({
  created() {
    this.loadEmployees();
  },
  methods: {
    loadEmployees() {
      console.log('loading employees...');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>
```